# Replace values in a List of Lists from a Map in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a Map that has all these values :

Map :

```
B Bonus
C Cash
D Draft
```

And I have a list of Lists :
`Account` :

```
Number, Type, Name
```

AccountsList

```
Account 0 : 123, B, Sam

Account 1 : 124, C, Harry
```

I have to update the values in AccountList based on Keyvalue pair in Map.

I have the below code:

```
for (Account acc: AccountList) {
        acc.setAccountType(map.get(acc.getAccountType()));
    }
```

How do I write the above code using Java 8 streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `forEach`:

```
AccountList.stream().forEach(acc -> acc.setAccountType(map.get(acc.getAccountType())))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by parallelStream:

```
AccountList = 
    AccountList.
    parallelStream().
    peek(
        acc -> acc.setAccountType(
                   map.get(acc.getAccountType())
               )
    ).collect(
        Collectors.toList()
    );
```

Comment: I would recommend to avoid this. Java's parallelStream uses Common ForkJoin thread pool over which you have no control whatsoever. The pool is shared across all your parallelStream calls, CompletableFutures (if not provided with custom thread pool). Additionally, using parallel processing adds extra overhead and complexity, and all other issues connected to Java's concurrency model. Long story short - if you're unsure you'd benefit from parallel processing, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return a new List without modifying the existing one

```
 List<AccountList> updatedAccountList = accountLists.stream().map(a -> {
            AccountList newAccountList = new AccountList();
            newAccountList.setType(map.get(a.getType()));
            return newAccountList;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: A new list will be created but values in this list will be modified.